# How to loop dates in SQL Based on month and year.?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to loop date from start to end based on month and year. For example

```
Month is 12 and year is 2014.

01 Dec 2014 
02 Dec 2014 
03 Dec 2014 
.
.

31 Dec 2014
```

Comment: Which database - sql server, postgres etc ?

Answer (score 1):

using `Recursive CTE`

```
with CTE
as
(
select N=0
UNION ALL 
select N+1 from CTE where N<30

)select CONVERT( CHAR(12),DATEADD(D,N,CAST('2014-12-01' as DATE)),106)  from CTE
```